# Exscript (paramiko) & Eclipse IDE: Authentication working when running the python module but failing when I try to use the Eclipse debugger

Tags: python, paramiko

Can anybody explain why the authentication is working when I run the python module in Eclipse but it is  failing when I try to use the Eclipse debugger for the same module?

Here is the output of the Python run:

```
Please enter your user name [admin]: 
Please enter your password:  
Attempting a connection to  Router1
ios: Rejecting ssh-rsa host key for Router1: 34h324h4324343h543h5h
Authenticating to  Router1

ios: Attempting to authenticate admin.
ios: Authenticating with _paramiko_auth_password
ios: Attempting to app-authenticate admin.
ios: waiting for: ['[\\r\\n][^\\r\\n]*(?:bad secrets|denied|invalid|too short|incorrect|connection timed out|failed|failure)', 'user ?name: ?$', '(?:s\\/key|otp-md4) (\\d+) (\\S+)', '(?:[\\r\\n]Password: ?|last resort password:)$', '[\\r\\n][\\-\\w+\\.:/]+(?:\\([^\\)]+\\))?[>#] ?$']
ios: Expecting a prompt
ios: Expected pattern: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003AB22D0>
ios: Shell prompt received.
ios: Expecting a prompt
ios: Expected pattern: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000003AB28B8>
ios: Checking '\r\n+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+ \r\n|                               WARNING                                 | \r\n|                               -------                                 | \r\n|                                                                       | \r\n| The confidential programs and data on this system are either licensed...... | \r\n|                                                                       | \r\n+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+ \r\n \r\nRouter1>' for errors
ios: Sending 'enable 8\n'
```

Here is the output of the debug:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7344)
Please enter your user name [admin]: 
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Please enter your password:  
Attempting a connection to  Router1
ios: Rejecting ssh-rsa host key for Router1: 34h324h4324343h543h5h
Authenticating to  Router1

ios: Attempting to authenticate admin.
ios: Authenticating with _paramiko_auth_password
ios: Authentication with _paramiko_auth_password failed
ios: Authenticating with _paramiko_auth_agent
ios: Authentication with _paramiko_auth_agent failed
ios: Authenticating with _paramiko_auth_autokey
ios: Authentication with _paramiko_auth_autokey failed
ios: Authenticating with _paramiko_auth_none
ios: Authentication with _paramiko_auth_none failed
```